# How to create Flow requests with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Retrofit and Coroutines in my application.

So I have two different Requests in my application. That I want to combine them with the [coroutine's combine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#combine).
If I want to combine two requests with each other, I need them to be `Flow`. But when I define my API requests to Flow I'll get an error:

```
   @GET("my_url")
   fun getHomeDataFlow(@Header("Authorization") token: String): Flow<Pagination<Home>>
```

The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<codenevisha.ir.app.journey.data.model.response.Pagination<codenevisha.ir.app.journey.data.model.response.Home>>
        for method APIService.getHomeDataFlow
```

This is my request implementation too:

```
 val homeFlow = oldRepository.getHomeDataFlow(params)
        val categoryFlow = oldRepository.getCategoriesFlow()
        var result = Pagination<Home>()

        homeFlow.combine(categoryFlow) { receivedHome, receivedCategory ->

            val home = Home()
            home.setCategory(receivedCategory)
            home.showType = Home.ShowType.CATEGORY.id
            receivedHome.results?.add(1, home)
            receivedHome

        }.collect {
            result = it
        }
```